# how to create a NodeJS application that is constantly checking my firebase database

Tags: node.js

I appreciate the help, I need to create a node application that is reviewing the changes in the firebase database, so that when it approaches a date and time there is registered it sends a push notification.

really so far I haven't been able to find a logical way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to schedule some event to be triggered, you can use [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

Or if you want to do something similar yourself, the solution might be something like this:

```
function checkUpdates(notificationTime) {
  checkDatabase();


  if (currentTime > notificationTime) {
    sendNotification();
    setTimeout(() => checkUpdates(nextNotificationTime));
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(() => checkUpdates(notificationTime), delayMs);
}
```